# Google Apps Script: How to solve the Exceeded maximum execution time error

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I want to extract the subject, plain_content and fromId of the last message of each thread in an inbox using Google Apps Script. I have 25k threads in my inbox. Whenever I run the code in the add on that I have made in Gmail, it gives me an error of exceeding maximum execution time. Can anyone please help to let me know how can I retrieve the required data from all 25k threads in an inbox without the error.

P.S - I do understand that there's no way to process all 25000 messages in a single call without exceeding the quota and I must monitor execution time and stop the script when the script runtime gets close to the one set by the quota (6 minutes runtime for personal accounts) and re-schedule the script to run again using ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName). But can anyone please help me know how can I use ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName) with the following function? I am pretty new to Javascript and GAS, so I am not really able to find a workaround to get the required data for 25k of emails.

```
function sendLabelName(){
  var labelNames = ["inbox", "spam"];
  var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabels();
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
    var userLabelName = labels[i].getName();
    labelNames.push(userLabelName);
  }
  Logger.log(labelNames)

  var inbox_list = [];
  var spam_list = [];
  var user_label_list = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < labelNames.length; j++){
    var currentLabelName = labelNames[j];
    getData(currentLabelName, inbox_list, spam_list, user_label_list);
  }

  var all_data = inbox_list.concat(spam_list, user_label_list);
  Logger.log('all_data' + all_data.length)
}

function getData(labelName, inbox_list, spam_list, user_label_list) {

  var startIndex = 0;
  var maxThreads = 500;
  var threads;

  do{

    if (labelName == "inbox"){
      threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(startIndex, maxThreads);  
      Logger.log(threads.length)
      for(var i = 0 ; i<threads.length; i++){
        var thread_messages = threads[i].getMessages();
        var thread_last_message = thread_messages[thread_messages.length - 1];
        var thread_subject = thread_last_message.getSubject();
        var thread_text_content = thread_last_message.getPlainBody();
        var thread_message_from = thread_last_message.getFrom();
        var inbox_thread_list = ["inbox", thread_subject, thread_text_content, thread_message_from];
        inbox_list.push(inbox_thread_list);
      }
      Logger.log(inbox_list.length)      
    }
    else if(labelName == "spam"){
        // do something with spam labels and make spam_list

      }
    }
    else{
         // do something with other labels and make user_label_list
      }
    }
    startIndex += maxThreads;
  } while (threads.length == maxThreads)
}
```

Comment: Do you need to do this regularly or just once?

Comment: `Logger.log` - comment out all Logger statements. The amount of time occupied by any Logger can be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

This solution focuses only on "Inbox" messages. Though you have anticipated processing for "Spam" and "User Labels", you didn't write any code for those.

The solution consists of two functions:

- `updateInboxThreadCount`

  - run this once before any processing and it will populate cell B1 of sheet=`inboxCounter` with the total number of Inbox messages. You can use this as a guide for how many times the main function should be run.
- `getInboxData`

  - uses the "start Index" and "Max Threads" values on "sheet=`inboxCounter`
  - also updates the "start Index" after each round of processing.
  - also increments a counter to show number of processing iterations.

---

```
// get the number of threads for the inbox 
// and write the total to the spreadsheet
function updateInboxThreadCount(){

  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "inboxCounter"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(threads.length)
}

// get last message of each thread from GMail

function getInboxData() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var counterSheetName = "inboxCounter"
  var counterSheet = ss.getSheetByName(counterSheetName)
  var indexes = counterSheet.getRange("B1:B5").getValues()
  var messagesSheetName = "messages"
  var messagesSheet = ss.getSheetByName(messagesSheetName)
  
  
    var messageArray = []
    // get index and counter variable values
    var startIndex = indexes[2][0]
    var maxThreads = indexes[1][0]
    var counter = indexes[3][0]
    var threads

    // get threads
    threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(startIndex, maxThreads)  
    for (var i = 0 ; i<threads.length; i++){
      var thisThread = threads[i]; // Get a specific thread
      var messages = thisThread.getMessages(); // Get the messages in that thread
      var messageCount = thisThread.getMessageCount(); // Count the number of messages in that thread
      var lastMessage = messages[messageCount - 1]; // Get the last message in that thread. The first message is numbered 0.
      messageArray.push(["inbox", lastMessage.getSubject(), lastMessage.getPlainBody(), lastMessage.getFrom()]);
    }
    // paste arrayvalues to sheet
    messagesLR = messagesSheet.getLastRow()
    messagesSheet.getRange(messagesLR+1,1,messageArray.length,4).setValues(messageArray)  

    // update the counter
    indexes[2][0] = startIndex + maxThreads+1
    indexes[3][0] = counter+1
    counterSheet.getRange("B1:B5").setValues(indexes)

    Logger.log(messageArray.length)      
}
```

---

**SAMPLE - "inboxCounter"**

[image: counter]

---

**SAMPLE - "messages"**

[image: sample]

---